# KeyError: False error pandas dataframe while using 'in' Membership Operators

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i was trying to compatre a part of the value of column in pandas using :

```
sameCls_m= df[(str(df['1']) in cls) | (str(df['2']) in cls)  ]
```

hear the value for df['1'] can be 12(alpha)
and cls as '12'
i wanted to make a dataframe that contains 12 in its value

but it gives KeyError: False  error

```
example : name   1        2      
      sh   12(alpha)  13(b)
      gh   11(c)      12(bit) 
      oj   4(c)       13(alpha)
```

now i want dataframe whose value from column '1' and '2' contains '12'
hear [sh, 12(alpha), 13(b)] [gh ,11(c), 12(bit)]

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: `str(df['1'])` very likely doesn't do what you expect. Provide an example and explain the logic.